# jquery toggle effect

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to make a dropdown effect, but I want to click on the div again so it slide up again :) How can i do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#panel').click(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'height' : '500px'
            },1000);
            $('#demo').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="panel">Hej med dig</div>
```

Comment: You want to make given div slide up on click, is that correct?

Comment: Could I ask: what's your (x)html mark-up? This seems an odd UI decision (albeit that's based on my answer using the various toggles).

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/666kwth here is what i have, and i want to click on it again so it slide up again

Answer (score 4):

I think:

```
$('#panel').click(
    function(){
        $(this).slideToggle(1000);
        $('#demo').fadeToggle(500);
    });
```

is what you're looking for.

References:

1. [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/),
2. [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

---

**Edited**

Given that your mark-up is, essentially:

```
<div id="panel">Hej med dig
    <div id="demo">Jeg er demo</div>    
</div>
```

The following jQuery should probably work more appropriately:

```
$('#panel').click(
    function(){
        $('#demo').slideToggle(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DjgD5/).

Comment: this is a good example however I might recommend a document.ready and no conflict method utilized, I'll post an example.

Comment: that was not what i was thinking of :/ this is what i have @David http://tinyurl.com/666kwth

Comment: Thanks @Nikita...you crazy aesthete, you..! =b @ole, how's the new version? I couldn't quite work out what you needed without the link (you subsequently provided) :)

Answer (score 0):

To be through you are going to want to wrap the entire slide function within the DOM ready jQuery function and utilize the noConflict method as well. This will ensure that the slide up and down will not be actionable until the entire document has loaded and the no conflict will ensure that it wont conflict with any other JS libraries or custom scripts you may have in place.

```
var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
$i(document).ready(function() {
  $i('#panel').click(function() {
    $i('#demo').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Note that the slide toggle function in jQuery 1.4.3 has some additional arguments that can be passed.

```
.slideToggle( [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
**duration** - string or number determining how long the animation will run.
**easing** - string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
**callback** - function to call once the animation is complete.
```

You can learn more about the slideToggle(); function and see real examples here:

[jQuery .slideToggle();](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in my demo. I grab initial value of height panel and use condition to define 
what height i use for animate method.

```
    $panel= $('#panel');
    init_height= $panel.css('height'); // grab initial value of height when DOM is ready
    $('#panel').click(function() {
        cur_height= $(this).css('height');
        (cur_height == '500px') ? height= init_height : height= '500px'; // conditional statement to define height for animate method;

        $(this).animate({
            'height' : height
        },1000);
        $('#demo').fadeIn(500);
    });
```

Hope it help you

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/ptJdm/)